# Data Factory check if an item exists in an array

Tags: arrays, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a DataFlow under Azure Data Factory and I need to check if my array contains values from another column. These are the information:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHHSg.png)

I have a table with 3 columns and I need to check if the value from the column 'job' is inside of the array of values of the column 'array'.
I create a derive column and use the expression:

> contains([array], [job]

)

But it gives me the error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZLM6.png)

Comment: please post the error as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `array` column may string type. Hence we need to write our expression to generate array type data first and then search `job` in it. Kindly consider using below expression.

```
contains(split(replace(replace(replace(arrayCol, '[', ''),']',''),'"'),','), #item == job)
```

Please check below screenshot where I tried same.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the find() function to check for the existence of a value in your arrays. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#find